# Can a professor post a grade online and then change it?

Tags: grading

Can a University professor post a grade on web-campus or blackboard and then change the grade the next day? Yesterday I received a B and today I it had been changed to a C... C's do not pass the class in the masters program.

Comment: Generally, yes. And most especially if the first grade was posted in error.

Comment: @guifa are you saying that there can ever be a case where it would be appropriate to do it when the original grade was _not_ posted in error?

Comment: @DanRomik Sure, what if one student requested a regrade which changed the curve for all other students.

Comment: @AustinHenley then you should suck it up and accept that grading is not an exact science. I don't think regrading a single student is an acceptable reason to change other students' grades.

Comment: @DanRomik from a student's literal perspective (what they see on Blackboard), sure. Calculated columns will change as more assignments that are factored into them are added. But even then that may be considered fixing an error. Consider my statement as merely trying to emphasis the likely corrective —as opposed to something arbitrary— action than anything else.

Comment: I don't know what the policies are in your university, however, given that this change of grade means now you do not pass your masters class, I would definitely ask for a word with the professor. If it was a mistake, then too bad for you, because C was your real/original grade. If it was not a mistake and he decided to change it last minute, then I guess you can ask why this change was made and be sure it was justified.

Answer (score 32):

In the US, universities generally have a policy that describes under what conditions a professor can change a grade that has been officially posted to the student's record.

For example, in my university, the official policy is that an instructor may change a final grade that has been officially posted to the student information system if there was an error (e.g. in the calculation of the grade) or if the instructor overlooked some work that the student submitted<sup>1</sup>. The web interface asks me to supply the reason when I submit the grade change request:

[image]

When I submit a grade change request after grades have been posted, it goes through another layer of approval (department head) but barring exceptional circumstances, these changes are routinely approved.

"Intermediate" or "unofficial" grades (e.g. grades that are posted in Blackboard but not in the official student information system, midterm grades, grades on assignments that aren't the final course grade, etc.) typically are not subject to those rules, and can be changed more easily.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although students persist in asking me to change their grades for [all kinds of other reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52pXO.png).

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I want to give an extra +1 for that bingo, which I reckon I'll distribute to my colleagues when finals week comes 'round.

Comment: @guifa Please allow me to join you for the +1.

Comment: My personal policy on grading mistakes is that I never lower the grade to a student: I correct a grading error only if it increases the grade.

Comment: @Massimo I have a similar policy, but I could imagine scenarios where it could be tricky; for example if all the rows in the spreadsheet used for grading calculations were shifted by 1 accidentally, so that every student in the class got another student's grade.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano and ff524, at the risk of sounding patronizing: your policy should be to not make such mistakes. When I enter final grades into the system, I check, then double-check, then double-double-check, triple-check etc., probably spending an hour or two on various forms of error-detection. I can think of few worse things to do to a student than mislead them about their final grades, even temporarily. (With that said, mistakes can still happen so I realize it's a slightly patronizing thing to say, but it's still a good policy to have even as a potentially unsatisfiable ideal.)

Comment: @ff524 and +100 for the grade bingo (saved it for future use). Any source for that or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: @DanRomik it's my original work ([first posted here in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496?m=26491565#26491565))

Comment: @DanRomik I agree with you, and in twenty years of teaching I've had to correct grading mistake 3-4 times at most, and they were mostly due to the student's unclear handwriting.

Comment: @ff524 cool! (and depressing at the same time; I always had a hard time accepting that someone getting a B could lead to a spiral of negative effects such as losing a scholarship, having to drop out of school, losing a visa and having to leave the country etc. - to me this is a sign that something is very wrong with the system, but I guess I'm going way off-topic here.)

Comment: @DanRomik When I have had to correct final grades, it's usually been because students only bother to tell me about an error in the grade of an earlier assessment (not the final exam) when they see that it affects their final grade. So after final grades are posted, they let me know that "I took this quiz a month ago and got a grade, but the grade is recorded as a zero" or "I did a demo of this lab assignment for the TA but it's not recorded" etc. With a large class, TAs participating in grading, and many low-stakes assessments (which I prefer), some errors are inevitable.

Comment: @DanRomik, there will always be borderline cases, even catastrophically so. I consider it my duty to give grades that (as far as humanly possible) fairly represent how much the student knows of *this* class, without reference to external (spurious) factors.

Comment: @vonbrand of course, I've also never let such factors affect my decision either... but it's still depressing. And in some other countries where people don't have to mortgage their house to send their kids to college it's much less common for a single grade to have catastrophic consequences, so your statement "there will always be borderline cases, even catastrophically so" is a bit misleading in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your school may also have a policy that, while the grades posted to the student information system are "released," they are not *final* until the final-exam period (and its grading window) has officially ended; say, the Monday after exam week.  The posting gives students an early glimpse of their assessment should they desire to launch an appeal (formal or otherwise), while also giving the instructor a holding area in which to post the final summation of the students' grades without the clutter of the many components composing it that might have clouded the waters on the learning management system, for example (and thus a chance to double-check them one last time).

There may also be an in-between option: that they are "released but not final" when posted, but become finalized 24 hours after whatever point they *are* posted (at which point it *does* become a bit more engraved, and thus a little more difficult to formally downgrade, or even upgrade).  This can then lead to deliberate delays, wherein instructors withhold the "official" grades for days at a time lest they lose their prerogative to change their minds amid student complaints. It's all easier if you just keep your gradebook separately, take your time, make your decision, and stick to it.